# Why do we care whether Hecke algebras are complete intersections?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

The title really says it all. I get the impression that proving certain Hecke algebras are complete intersections is a crucial step in the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem. But how do you use a result like that? Intuitive or technical answers both welcome!

Comment: I could give quite a long answer to this, but it's quite hard to gauge the correct level of technical details to give in this setting. The specific use of this condition in Wiles is a little subtle, but the fact that one might expect $R$ to be a complete intersection is related to a description of $R$ as an intersection of the unobstructed global deformation ring (which one also expects is a complete intersection) with a (often smooth) local deformation ring and one expects the intersection to be transverse in Wiles' setting.